# Is this "Canvas2D: Multiple readback" be the reason of losing frames?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I've to use OpenCV.js to capture frames of an html `<video>` so I can apply a grey-level filter to these frames the store it for further use. When showing the treated video on a canva using `cv.imshow("greyVideo", matGry);` after each frame, it seems it's working. however, the array containing the treated frames is not long enough : its length is ~230 instead of ~320 (32 seconds, 10 FPS).
Let's see my code :

```js
//Variables for canvas
var matClr;
var matGry;
var captur;

// Variable for storing frames
var framesGry = [];

//Variables for working 
var streamingOn = false;
const FPS = 10;
var compteur = 1;

async function demarrerTraitement(){
    let afficheur = document.getElementById("ntm"); 
    console.log("demarrage traitement")
    //Initializing matrix and capture object;
    const hauteur = afficheur.height;
    const largeur = afficheur.width;
    streamingOn = true;

    matClr = new cv.Mat(hauteur, largeur, cv.CV_8UC4);
    matGry = new cv.Mat(hauteur, largeur, cv.CV_8UC1);
    captur = await new cv.VideoCapture(afficheur);    
    traitement();
}

function arretTraitement(){
    console.trace("arretTraitement : vidéo terminée");
    streamingOn = false;    
}


function traitement(){
    if(streamingOn == false){
        console.warn("detectContourVideo - sortie : traitement fini. %o frames traitées.", compteur);
        compteur = 1;
    }

    else{
        const length = 480 * 480;
        frameVide = Array(length).fill(0).toString();
        // Reading capture object into matClr
        captur.read(matClr);
        // Applying filter
        cv.cvtColor(matClr, matGry, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        // updating canva of grey "video"
        cv.imshow("greyVideo", matGry);
        // Extracting pixels data
        let frame = matGry.data.slice(); // Slice is essential or I copy a reference
 
        framesGry.push(frame);
        compteur = compteur + 1;

        setTimeout(traitement, 1000/FPS); // Supposed to call the function each new frame
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>handwashing</title>
        <!-- JS -->
            <!-- API -->
            <script src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="./javascript/traitement.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <video src="" id = "ntm" width="480" height="480" controls src="demo.webm" ></video>
            <canvas id="greyVideo"></canvas>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

So checks are required ! When I look closer to the displaying canva, it's subtile, but I can swear I see the grey video (in a canvas) is "speeder" than the color video (in html `<video>`) Like, it's jumping to next frames (I´d like to record my screen to show you what I see, but I don´t know how to add video here.)

Maybe the delay in setTimeout is too short ? I tried changing the value of `FPS`, but the issue is still the same, not enough frames in my array, until `FPS = 1` but Iḿ loosing too much informations ! So I finally decided to give a closer look to a warn I've in the console about `captur.read(matClr);` instruction :

> Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true.

I ignored it since times, cause it seemed to work despite of it. but now, it's ;y last idea. Can this `willReadFrequently` attribute be the origin of my lose of frames ? I I´d like to set up this attribute to `true`, but [the link provided with the warn](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently) explain how to do this about a `cv.canva` object, however, my issue is about a `cv.VideoCapture` object, and according to the [datasheet](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html), it doesn't have a `setAttribute` methode. It's the C++ version datasheet, but even if I give it a try, I, of course, have the error "captur.setAttribute is not a function". Can I try something else ?
I'm pretty sure the issue is from this `cv.VideoCapture` object because even if I delete the instruction to thisplay the grey video in the canva, I still have this warning, and the same number of frames.